# Relative Layout width changing but not height?

Tags: android, android-layout

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.something);
layout.getLayoutParams().width = 900;
layout.getLayoutParams().height = 900;
```

The width changes to what I set it to, but the height doesn't no matter what I change it to. I tried changing the layout_height in the XML to 10 dp, but that did nothing as well. I have also tried:

```
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 320;
params.width = 320;
```

but the same problem occurred.

Comment: For moment, simply remove the Scroll View and you will see that it works. Then read about why it doesn't (hint: search engine). Learn about onMeasure, onLayout, ViewGroups and ScrollView in general. At the end of the day, you will be a better Android dev :). Also, are you calling invalidateLayout() (or similar?).

Comment: Removing ScrollView worked, Thanks :)